# How to pull an API from Kimono

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp

We're looking for the best way to pull an API from Kimono Labs and how to structure properly. [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Mo4lsDmvWFMiv6fk8Xp?p=preview)

Here is what we have in the app.js

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('Calendar', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/42ts6px8?apikey=363e7e1d3fffb45d424ad535ebdc233d&callback=kimonoCallback')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.events = res.data[0].events;                
        });
});
```

index...

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Todos $http</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      function kimonoCallback(data) {
        // do something with the data
        // please make sure the scope of this function is global
      }

      $.ajax({
        "url":"http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/42ts6px8?apikey=363e7e1d3fffb45d424ad535ebdc233d&callback=kimonoCallback",
        "crossDomain":true,
        "dataType":"jsonp"
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Calendar">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in events">
      <h1>{{item.EventTitles.text}}</h1>
      <img src="{{item.HeadlineImages.src}}">
      <p>{{item.eventdescription}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Are we doing this correctly? We can get it to pull data from a local .json file... but not from Kimono?

Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, I am aware of the API link from Kimono Labs I included does not work, this is intentional.

**EDIT2:** Added a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Mo4lsDmvWFMiv6fk8Xp?p=preview) if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kimono actually has a tutorial for calling your API with Angular.js. You can take a look at it through their docs at: https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/204380310-Tutorial-Calling-Kimono-with-AngularJS-

They also have pretty solid support if you email or chat them, in my experience.